# Zooming in a WebView:always zooms the right side

Tags: android, android-webview

I created an Activity that launches a website on a WebView, i added pinch to zoom support and zoom controls. My problem: when i want to zoom the left part from the website, by using pinch to zoom, or controls, there is always the right side that is displayed and not the left one, when i want to scrool to the left, the webview is "blocked" i mean it just shows the right side that's it. I hope that you are understanding me!
Here is the code that im using:

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

        mWebView.setInitialScale(65);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
            {
             //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to Loading...
            MyActivity.setTitle("Loading...");
             MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded

             // Return the app name after finish loading
                if(progress == 100)
                   MyActivity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
              }
            });
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new Manipulation());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebView.loadUrl("myURL");
```

Do you have an idea please of how solving that zoom problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class WebViewHelp extends Activity {
//specify url to open
    String url="";
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Uri uri=Uri.parse(url);
        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
        startActivity(i);
    }



}
```

Comment: This is to launch the browser i guess! For me i want to show the website on a webview! I did it but i have zooming problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
   //xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
>
  <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  />
</LinearLayout>


//Activity
 public class Main extends Activity {
//specify the url to open
String url="";
  private WebView myWebView;
  private static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams ZOOM_PARAMS =
new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
Gravity.BOTTOM);

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    this.myWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    FrameLayout mContentView = (FrameLayout) getWindow().
    getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    final View zoom = this.myWebView.getZoomControls();
    mContentView.addView(zoom, ZOOM_PARAMS);
    zoom.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    this.myWebView.loadUrl(url);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tested your code and same problem. You want to check? open your activity, try to zoom a left part, and you'll see that you can't do it! it just zooms the right side+ horizental scrolling is blocked !